# How to launch new instance instead focussing existing on on click on application-icon

Tags: macos, info.plist, launch-services

Is there a way to let the application start a new instance and not to focus an existing application if you click on the icon of the application? Probably there is a way for the LaunchServices and it's property-file info.plist.

E.G. If you have TextEdit in Dock an click the first time on it it starts a new application. But the second click focusses the existing one.

Only the direct call in terminal starts always a new instance:

```
/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit &
```

Comment: To clarify: when the user clicks on your application icon in the dock, instead of switching to the application they clicked, it starts a new one?

Comment: No currently not. This is the general and usual way, but your/my way is what I want it to do - just start a new instance